# How to format dates without spaces r

Tags: r, strptime, as.date

I can do this

`strptime("20150615",format="%Y%m%d")`

But this won't work.

`strptime("194207","%Y%m")
[1] NA`

Whats is going on here?

**Edit**

For now doing this but so silly.

`strptime(paste("194207","01"),"%Y%m%d")`

Comment: There is no year-month format in base r. Have a look at the zoo package for `yearmon`.

Comment: Why is so silly `strptime(paste0("194207","01"),"%Y%m%d")`?

Comment: Weird, I would have expected from `?strptime` that year/month would work: "For strptime the input string need not specify the date completely: it is assumed that unspecified seconds, minutes or hours are zero, and an unspecified year, month or day is the current one."

Comment: @agstudy My question was different "yyyymm" vs "yyyy-mm".

Comment: @CCurtis really different ? For me it is a duplicated , if community  decides differently it will reopen it.